# Model path of bullet to hit future position of balloon

Tags: physics, python, projectile-physics, tower-defense

I am coding a Bloons Tower Defense Game and one of the problems I have is how to shoot a projectile from a tower and have it hit a balloon that is moving along a certain path. The way I am currently moving my balloon is by having a list(length approximately 15) which stores different pixels the balloon has to reach(which essentially defines its path). Then for every frame I calculated the difference in x and y for the pixel I am currently on in the list and the pixel in the next index. I use some trig to add to then change the x and y position of the balloon to reach closer to the next pixel in the list. The method is shown here:

```
    def move(self):
        x1, y1 = self.path[self.path_index]
        x2, y2 = self.path[self.path_index + 1]

        changex = x2 - x1
        changey = y2 - y1
        angle = math.atan2(changey, changex)

        self.x += math.cos(angle) * self.velocity
        self.y += math.sin(angle) * self.velocity

        if round(self.x) == x2 and round(self.y) == y2:
            self.path_index += 1
```

If the balloon was traveling in a straight line it would be super easy to shoot a bullet such that it hits the balloon, however, the path has several turns and curves, and I am not sure how to create some method which sends the bullet in a certain direction such that the bullet hits the balloon no matter what. Im guessing I have to do some future balloon position predictions in code but that seems inefficient and I am not really sure if that will even work so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the targets move along a path defined as a series of points. So, effectively, it is moving along a series of straight segments, correct?

Thus, you could:

1. Solve the time and position for the collision along the current segment.
2. Check if that position is beyond the end of the segment.
3. If it is, add a time offset for the time to reach the end of the segment, take the next segment as current, and repeat from step 1.
4. If you still have not found a viable interception after considering the last path segment, then you cannot intercept this target. Try a different target, wait, or shoot to miss.

Makes sense?

---

Ok, we have:

- The shooter position. I'll call it `s_pos`.
- The bullet speed. I'll call it `b_speed`.
- The target initial position. I'll call it `t_pos_0`.
- The target velocity. I'll call it `t_vel`.
- The time offset. I'll call it `time_0`.

And we want:

- Collision time.
- Collision position.

We know that the distance the bullet would have traveled in function of time is:

```
b_travel_dist(time) = b_speed * time_0 + b_speed * time
```

I'll take the first terms to be computed before hand:

```
b_travel_dist_0 = b_speed * time_0
```

And now we have:

```
b_travel_dist(time) = b_travel_dist_0 + b_speed * time
```

If we can find the function of the distance of the target to the shooter in terms of time, the point where these functions cross is the solution.

We can start with the position of the target as a function of time:

```
t_pos(time) = t_pos_0 + t_vel * time
```

And then the offset between target and shooter as a function of time:

```
ts_offset(time) = t_pos(time) - s_pos
```

And then their distance:

```
ts_dist(time) = length(ts_offset(time))
```

So we can equate the distance between target and shooter and the distance the bullet traveled:

```
ts_dist(time) = b_travel_dist(time)
```

Replacing:

```
length(t_pos_0 + t_vel * time - s_pos) = b_travel_dist_0 + b_speed * time
```

Actually, I want to reorganize it so that the terms that do not have time are together:

```
length(t_pos_0 - s_pos + t_vel * time) = b_speed * time
```

In fact, you can take those to compute beforehand too:

```
ts_offset_0 = t_pos_0 - s_pos
```

And we have a little less cognitive load:

```
length(ts_offset_0 + t_vel * time) = b_travel_dist_0 + b_speed * time
```

And then we solve for time (we of course know the time must be positive)… Hmm…

Look, we can divide by time on both sides (take your time to think it through):

```
length(ts_offset_0/time + t_vel) = b_travel_dist_0/time + b_speed
```

Ok, let us separate the x and y components:

```
sqrt
(
    (ts_offset_0.x/time + t_vel.x)^2
    +
    (ts_offset_0.y/time + t_vel.y)^2
)
=
b_travel_dist_0/time + b_speed
```

So we can square both sides:

```
(ts_offset_0.x/time + t_vel.x)^2
+
(ts_offset_0.y/time + t_vel.y)^2
=
(b_travel_dist_0/time + b_speed)^2
```

Let us expand those:

```
(ts_offset_0.x/time)^2 + 2*(ts_offset_0.x/time)(t_vel.x) + (t_vel.x)^2
+
(ts_offset_0.y/time)^2 + 2*(ts_offset_0.y/time)(t_vel.y) + (t_vel.y)^2
=
(b_travel_dist_0/time)^2 + 2*(b_travel_dist_0/time)(b_speed) + (b_speed)^2
```

Reorganize:

```
  (ts_offset_0.x/time)^2
+ (ts_offset_0.y/time)^2
+ 2*(ts_offset_0.x/time)(t_vel.x)
+ 2*(ts_offset_0.y/time)(t_vel.y)
+ (t_vel.x)^2
+ (t_vel.y)^2
=
  (b_travel_dist_0/time)^2
+ 2*(b_travel_dist_0/time)(b_speed)
+ (b_speed)^2
```

Reorganize harder:

```
  (ts_offset_0.x)^2/time^2
+ (ts_offset_0.y)^2/time^2
+ 2*(ts_offset_0.x)(t_vel.x)/time
+ 2*(ts_offset_0.y)(t_vel.y)/time
+ (t_vel.x)^2
+ (t_vel.y)^2
=
  (b_travel_dist_0)^2/time^2
+ 2*(b_travel_dist_0)(b_speed)/time
+ (b_speed)^2
```

Reorganize harder:

```
  ((ts_offset_0.x)^2 + (ts_offset_0.y)^2)/time^2
+ (2*(ts_offset_0.x)(t_vel.x) + 2*(ts_offset_0.y)(t_vel.y))/time
+ (t_vel.x)^2 + (t_vel.y)^2
=
  (b_travel_dist_0)^2/time^2
+ 2*(b_travel_dist_0)(b_speed)/time
+ (b_speed)^2
```

Let us multiply everything by time squared:

```
  (ts_offset_0.x)^2 + (ts_offset_0.y)^2
+ time * (2*(ts_offset_0.x)(t_vel.x) + 2*(ts_offset_0.y)(t_vel.y))
+ time^2 * (t_vel.x)^2 + (t_vel.y)^2
=
  (b_travel_dist_0)^2
+ time * 2*(b_travel_dist_0)(b_speed)
+ time^2 * (b_speed)^2
```

Reorganize again:

```
  time^2 * (t_vel.x)^2 + (t_vel.y)^2
+ time * (2*(ts_offset_0.x)(t_vel.x) + 2*(ts_offset_0.y)(t_vel.y))
+ (ts_offset_0.x)^2 + (ts_offset_0.y)^2
=
  time^2 * (b_speed)^2
+ time * 2*(b_travel_dist_0)(b_speed)
+ (b_travel_dist_0)^2
```

Ah, a quadratic equation in canonical form:

```
  time^2 * ((t_vel.x)^2 + (t_vel.y)^2 - (b_speed)^2)
+ time * ((2*(ts_offset_0.x)(t_vel.x) + 2*(ts_offset_0.y)(t_vel.y)) - 2*(b_travel_dist_0)(b_speed))
+ (ts_offset_0.x)^2 + (ts_offset_0.y)^2 - (b_travel_dist_0)^2
=
0
```

Let us take the parts out:

```
a = (t_vel.x)^2 + (t_vel.y)^2 - (b_speed)^2
b = (2*(ts_offset_0.x)(t_vel.x) + 2*(ts_offset_0.y)(t_vel.y)) - 2*(b_travel_dist_0)(b_speed)
c = (ts_offset_0.x)^2 + (ts_offset_0.y)^2 - (b_travel_dist_0)^2
```

Wait, I want to write those another way:

```
a = t_vel.dot(t_vel) - b_speed * b_speed
b = 2 * ts_offset_0.dot(t_vel) - 2 * b_travel_dist_0 * b_speed
c = ts_offset_0.dot(ts_offset_0) - b_travel_dist_0 * b_travel_dist_0
```

And we have:

```
a * time^2 + b * time + c = 0
```

Let us cut to it, and use the quadratic formula. We have two solutions:

```
time = (-b + sqrt(b^2 - 4ac))/2a
```

And

```
time = (-b - sqrt(b^2 - 4ac))/2a
```

We want the smaller positive one.

---

To recap we compute these beforehand:

```
b_travel_dist_0 = b_speed * time_0
ts_offset_0 = t_pos_0 - s_pos
```

Then these:

```
a = t_vel.dot(t_vel) - b_speed * b_speed
b = 2 * ts_offset_0.dot(t_vel) - 2 * b_travel_dist_0 * b_speed
c = ts_offset_0.dot(ts_offset_0) - b_travel_dist_0 * b_travel_dist_0
```

And finally these:

```
times = [
    (-b + sqrt(b^2 - 4ac))/2a,
    (-b - sqrt(b^2 - 4ac))/2a
]
```

That is, of course, riddled with pitfalls. Namely division by zero and square root of negative numbers.

That is because we are looking for a solution when the shooter shoots at time zero. So the solution is simple: if computing this is invalid… Don't shoot. Skip the segment. If you reach the end of the path, check again next frame.

To ease computing the times, I'll do this instead:

```
bb = b * b
a2 = 2 * a
ac4 = 4 * a * c
```

And then we can do this:

```
if bb >= ac4:
    r = sqrt(bb - ac4)
    times = [
        (-b + r)/a2,
        (-b - r)/a2
    ]
```

Let us find if there is a valid time:

```
    time = INF
    for candidate_time in times:
        if candidate_time < 0.0:
            continue

        if candidate_time < time:
            time = candidate_time

    if not is_inf(time):
        pass
```

You can compute the point to aim simply like this:

```
t_pos_0 + t_vel * time
```

---

Alright, but we need to check if it is within this segment, otherwise we have to loop, right? right. So we do something like this:

```
t_index = index
while t_index + 1 < t_points.size():
    next_point = t_points[t_index + 1]
    t_vel = (next_point - t_pos_0).normalized() * t_speed
    time_to_next_point = (next_point - t_pos_0).length() / t_speed

    # OTHER STUFF SHOWN BEFORE GOES HERE

    if not is_inf(time):
        if time <= time_to_next_point:
            # INSERT SHOOT CODE HERE
            return

    time_0 += time_to_next_point
    t_pos_0 = next_point
    t_index += 1
```

Yes, I have tested this. *In Godot with GDScript. Which is what I have been writing here in the last parts of the answer. It is not Python, but it has very similar syntax. So I hope it is not hard to adapt.*